# How is Cassandra sorting static column families

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

As far as I know, a comparator is specified on the column family level. So far I have use it with dynamic columns (wide-rows). Which type of comparator is Cassandra using when you create a static column family using CQL?

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  title text,
  album text,
  artist text,
  data blob
);
```

and what happens if you throw a composite key into the mix.

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
  id uuid,
  title text,
  album text,
  artist text,
  data blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id, title), album)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#createTablepartitionClustering

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html

> On a given physical node, rows for a given partition key are stored in the order induced by the clustering columns.

So in the 2nd case your partition key is `(id, title)`, and clustering key is `album`, meaning all the rows for a given partition key will be stored ordered by `album`

Comment: Alright but how are the non-primary key columns ordered if you don't specify a comparator on the column family. The ordering is important to be able to do slicing. But i think it's just using a `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type`

Comment: Yeah, they are sorted by column name